# How to get USB device name through windows Command Prompt or PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I am trying to get the USB device name that is displayed in the Control Panel>Hardware>Device and Printers
eg.QEMU USB keyboard here: [image: QEMU USB keyboard]

I am not sure if this can be done.
I have tried using both:

1. `wmic path Win32_USBControllerDevice get Dependent | find "USB"`
2. `gwmi Win32_USBControllerDevice |%{[wmi]($_.Dependent)} | Sort
   Manufacturer,Description,DeviceID | Ft -GroupBy Manufacturer
   Description,Service,DeviceID`

But I can not get it.
Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the Printers is pretty simple:

```
Get-Printer | select Name
```

Devices is trickier, and querying your USBController device probably isn't the right way.

I can query Win32_PnpEntity and get much closer, but why when `Get-PnpDevice` is much easier and looks to be about the same results.

Additionally I can pipe that to `Get-PnpDeviceProperty`

```
Get-pnpdevice | ForEach-Object { Get-PnpDeviceProperty -InstanceId $_.InstanceId  | select Data}
```

and try to figure it out from there.

I don't think there is anything provided to give you easy access to the friendly device names. It might be easier to use PowerShell to search the registry for stored values.

Lastly, I was only able to get as close as something that looked like this:

```
{D781FE0F-49E3-5FFD-BC34-A48286BFE47A}
Generic PnP Monitor
DISPLAY\DEL4090\1&8713BCA&0&UID0
ROOT\BasicDisplay\0000
False
{D781FE0F-49E3-5FFD-BC34-A48286BFE47A}
False
False
False
False
False
3
Generic Monitor
monitor.inf:*PNP09FF,PnPMonitor.Install
0
monitor.inf:91d2a0f3f5cc9ebd:PnPMonitor.Install:10.0.15063.0:*PNP09FF
ROOT\BasicDisplay\0000
7/14/2017 7:51:39 PM
7/14/2017 7:51:39 PM
7/14/2017 7:51:39 PM
7/14/2017 7:51:39 PM
6/20/2006 7:00:00 PM
10.0.15063.0
Generic PnP Monitor
monitor.inf
PnPMonitor.Install
*PNP09FF
Microsoft
16719872
```

Not the most promising start.